# Cannot send json to express server from the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I established 2 servers: the first one is for frontend (localhost:7200), the second one is for backend (localhost:7300). And there is a test request made by frontend to backend, correspondingly, on a route '/test'.

The problem is when I send a json object (when 'btn' button is clicked) it rejects with the following message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7300/test' from origin 'http://localhost:7200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Of course, I  set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on backend (see below).

This happens if I set 'Content-Type' header as 'application/json'. But it works fine if there is no header set at all or the header is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' (and, therefore, the message sent is not JSON-like).

The code on frontend

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:7300/test', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    xhr.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.responseText);
    });

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({name: 'kek'}))
});
```

The code on backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
  // res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
  console.log(req.body)
  res.json({success: true});
});
```

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Now it works, thanks! But do you have any idea why it doesn't work if headers are set manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the headers when your server responds to a POST request.

> ```
> app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
>   res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
>   res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
> ```

The error message says:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

The preflight request is an OPTIONS request, not a POST request, so the headers are not set in the response to it and the POST request is never made.

---

Use the [standard `cors` middleware library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cors` middleware. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

This middleware automatically set headers to avoid CORS issues (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Thank you. I marked another answer as the solution, but this article helped me too. I voted your answer up